# Variable Number of Arguments table

Tags: lua, arguments

In lua I'm using someone elses function that takes variable number of arguments. What I would like to be able to do is build the argument list via loop. Is this possible?

Example function:

```
printResult = ""

function print (...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    printResult = printResult .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
  printResult = printResult .. "\n"
end
```

I tried

```
print({"test","test2"})
```

But that just passes one argument (the table) to the function

Comment: Use `{...}` instead of `arg`.

Comment: Like I said it's not my function. But I tried what you suggested in test function but the result was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) function. You can build the arguments to the vararg function you want to call in a table. Calling `table.unpack` on the table will expand the table into an argument list. Like so,

```
args = {}
for i = 1, 4 do
    args[#args+1] = i * i * math.pi
end

print(table.unpack(args))
```

Also, you will need in the `print` function you posted to gather all those arguments into the `arg` list that you are using...

```
function print (...)
  printResult = ""
  arg = {...}
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    printResult = printResult .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
  printResult = printResult .. "\n"
  return printResult
end
```

Finally, there is already a way to accomplish what you are trying to do using [`table.concat`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.concat).

```
function print(...)
    return table.concat({...}, "\t").."\n"
end
```